# printf %e scientific notation giving wrong value in C

Tags: c, printf, scientific-notation

I'm doing a very basic printout of scientific notation.

But, it appears to me its not working and I can't figure out why?

Code:

```
size_t result = 0;
printf("%e \n",result);
```

Value it prints is below:

```
1.278341e-307
```

What would be right way to do scientific notations?

Comment: This looks like rounding error from machine precision.

Comment: solution suggests answer should be  0.000000e+000 - how to achieve that and get over rounding error ?

Comment: Why do you need to output `size_t` in scientific notation?

Comment: I changed it to int result - but still get same value ..

Comment: The program is invalid. Turn your warnings knob to 11 and leave it there. Your compiler will tell you.

Comment: Dude - printf %e for an integral value?  Really???

Comment: @paulsm4 - sorry I am still a novice who does embarrassing mistakes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use a floating-point printf format code, like `%e`, the matching argument must be a `double`. But you are passing it an integer (`size_t`).

Printf does not know the types of its arguments, so you have to tell it what they are by using the correct format code. If you lie to it, you will get undefined results.

And if you are using gcc or clang, please always use the `-Wall` command-line option and *read the warnings*. That will save all of us a lot of trouble.

Comment: got it - thank u for the explanation - seems I need to read printf formatting and cant take it for granted :)